# adding text before and after a link jSoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I've just stared learning Jsoup and the cookbook on their website but I'm just a bit stuck with addling text to an element I've parsed.

```
try{

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();    
            Element add = doc.prependText("a href") ;
            Elements links = add.select("a[href]");                 

                for (Element link : links) {                        


                PrintStream sb =    System.out.format("%n %s",link.attr("abs:href"));

                System.out.print("<br>");
                                        }       

    }       
    catch(Exception e){         
        System.out.print("error --> " + e);
    }
```

Example run with google.com I get

```
 http://www.google.ie/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi<br>
 http://maps.google.ie/maps?hl=en&tab=wl<br>
 https://play.google.com/?hl=en&tab=w8<br>
```

But I really want

```
<a href> http://www.google.ie/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi<br></a>
<a href> http://maps.google.ie/maps?hl=en&tab=wl<br></a>
<a href> https://play.google.com/?hl=en&tab=w8<br></a>
```

With this code I've gotten all the links off the page but I want to also get the  and  tags so I can them create my on webpage. I've tried adding a string and prepend text but just can't seem to get it right.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

with `link.attr(...)` you get the attribute *value*.

But you need the whole tag:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(...).get();


for( Element e : doc.select("a[href]") ) // Select all 'a'-Tags with 'href' attribute
{
    String wholeTag = e.toString(); // Get a string as the element is

    /* No you you can use the html - in this example for a simple output */
    System.out.println(wholeTag);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, if I use that it prints every thing on the page images too, so is it just a case of using better element to narrow it down to just getting the text and the href link.

Comment: Ok, can you post the html part where you want to select your links? Maybe there are some things you can use to find only the proper links.